# F is not defined

Tags: javascript

F is not defined. Here is my code. Discord.js. Im confused why it is not working

```
jsfile.forEach(f, i => {
        let pull = require(`/commands/${f}`);
        bot.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
        pull.config.aliases.forEach(alias => {
            bot.aliases.set(alias, pull.config.name)

ReferenceError: f is not defined
```

Comment: You need parenthesis around `f, i` → `(f, i) => { /*rest of code here */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
forEach(f, i => {
```

This doesnt work. It only works if you have 1 argument. If you have more then 1 then you need to wrap it in parenthensis:

```
forEach((f, i) => {
```